# Can I use Dynamics 365 for Sitecore Connector to send data from Sitecore Form directly to Dynamics 365?

Tags: sitecore-forms, dynamics-crm-module

I would like to use Sitecore Forms to collect data from my Sitecore website, then send that data directly to Dynamics 365 - using the Connector that is available from Sitecore.

I have looked for examples of how to do this online, but there doesnt seem to be any solid example of how to do this specifically for Sitecore forms. Most examples, including the sitecore documentation are dependent on XConnect. The closest example I could find synced contacts, together with events from each contacts interactions.

In my specific situation, I already have access to the users ContactId in Dynamics, so would like to create a simpler pipeline, that takes forms from the experience database (that have not been processed yet) and send them periodically to Dynamics.

Can anyone provide example of how this might be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Define source entity (Form)**

First of all you need to define the data structure of the data coming from your form. To do this, create a folder called **Forms** `Data Access/Value Accessor Sets/Providers/` and child **Form Model** of type `Value Accessor Set`. Under your Form Model, add a new `Property Value Accessor` for each property being sent through the form – specify the relevant Property Name in each.

**2. Define target entity (Incident)**

Next you need to define the structure of the entity you need to create in dynamics. To do this, locate the folder called **Dynamics** `Data Access/Value Accessor Sets/Providers/Dynamics`. Add a child **Incident** of type `Value Accessor Set` to represent your dynamics entity. Under this, add a child of type `Entity Attribute Value Accessor` for each property that is required to create the entity – specify Attribute Name.

**3. Define the mapping between source and target**

Create a new `Value Mapping Sets Folder` called **Forms** to Dynamics Mappings in this location `Dyanamics Tenant/Value Mapping Sets`. Under this, add a new `Value Mapping Set` called **Form to Incident**. Then add a new `Value Mapping` for each property you want to map between source (form) and target (dynamics entity). In each of these define source and target from the previous sections.

**4. Create a new template**

Create a new pipeline step template called **Read Form Data** (with base template Base Pipeline Step). Add a field called **Form Guid** `single-line text` and also any other settings that might be useful.

**5. Create FormSettings and FormModel classes**

The properties that are contained within these classes will depend entirely on your own setup. The ***FormModel*** class should contain **exactly the same** properties that you define in the source section (1) above. Note, you can define any types of property here (i.e. `EntityReference, OptionSet, Guid, AssociateRequest`). These will be mapped through in the same format to the target entity. The FormSettings class should match exactly the additional settings you defined in the new template (step 4).

**6. Create the following class ReadFormDataStepConverter**

This class effectively reads our settings and makes them available inside the pipeline processor. Note - The `SupportedId` in this class should use the ID from your new template (step 4)

using Sitecore.DataExchange.Attributes;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.BatchHandling;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Converters.PipelineSteps;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Extensions;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Models;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Repositories;
using Sitecore.Services.Core.Model;
using YourNameSpace.Models;

```
namespace YourNameSpace.PipelineSteps
{
    [SupportedIds(new string[] { "{E65B7E7C-44AB-4071-B040-3D3F7835AAAC}" })]
    public class ReadFormDataStepConverter : BasePipelineStepConverter
    {
        public const string FieldNameBatchEntryStoragePluginLocation = "BatchEntryStoragePluginLocation";

        public const string FormGuid = "FormGuid";
        
        /** DEFINE OTHER SETTINGS HERE **/ 

        public ReadFormDataStepConverter(IItemModelRepository repository)
            : base(repository)
        {
        }

        protected override void AddPlugins(ItemModel source, PipelineStep pipelineStep)
        {
            BatchEntryStorageSettings batchEntryStorageSettings = new BatchEntryStorageSettings
            {
                PluginLocation = GetGuidValue(source, "BatchEntryStoragePluginLocation")
            };
            FormSettings formSettings = new FormSettings
            {
                FormGuid = GetStringValue(source, "Form Guid")
                
                /** RETRIEVE OTHER SETTINGS HERE **/

            };
            pipelineStep.AddPlugins(batchEntryStorageSettings, formSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

**7. Create the following class ReadFormDataStepProcessor**

This class effectively reads form data from the ExperienceForms table and places a collection of FormModels in the Iteratable Context. Which will be consumed by a future pipeline.

```
using System;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Attributes;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Contexts;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Models;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data;
using Sitecore.Services.Core.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using YourNameSpace.Models;

namespace YourNameSpace.PipelineSteps
{
    [RequiredPipelineStepPlugins(new Type[]
        {
    typeof(FormSettings)
        })]
    public class ReadFormDataStepProcessor : BasePipelineStepProcessor
    {
        private IFormDataProvider _formDataProvider;
        private IFileStorageProvider _fileStorageProvider;

        public ReadFormDataStepProcessor()
        {
            _formDataProvider = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFormDataProvider>();
            _fileStorageProvider = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFileStorageProvider>();
        }
        protected override void ProcessPipelineStep(PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
        {
            // These are read from pipeline root via ReadFormDataStepConverter
            var formSettings = pipelineStep.GetPlugin<FormSettings>();
            DateRangeSettings dateRangeSettings = pipelineContext.GetPlugin<DateRangeSettings>();

            // FormGuid identifies a specific form template
            var formdata = _formDataProvider.GetEntries(new Guid(formSettings.FormGuid), dateRangeSettings.LowerBound, dateRangeSettings.UpperBound);

            var formModels = new List<FormModel>();
            foreach (var item in formdata)
            {
                var newForm = new FormModel();

                newForm.FormId = item.FormEntryId.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newForm.FormId)) newForm.FormIdGuid = new Guid(newForm.FormId);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newForm.FormId)) newForm.EnquiryEntity = new EntityReference("incident", newForm.FormIdGuid);

                newForm.SomeProperty = item.Fields.Where(x => x.FieldName == "SomeProperty").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                
                /** ADD OTHER PROPERTIES **/

                /** EXAMPLE OF USING SETTINGS **/
                newForm.ProcessType = new OptionSetValue(formSettings.ProcessType);
                
                formModels.Add(newForm);
            }
            IterableDataSettings newPlugin = new IterableDataSettings(formModels);
            string message = ((formModels.Count > 0) ? $"Forms read from manager. (total count: {formModels.Count})" : "No forms were read from manager.");
            Log(logger.Info, pipelineContext, message);
            pipelineContext.AddPlugin(newPlugin);
        }
    }
}
```

**8. Create your pipelines**

We will use the Sitecore Out-of-the-box tools to create all but one of the pipeline steps. Create two new pipelines as defined below:

***Read Forms Pipeline***

- Add dynamics queue `Create Entity Queue Pipeline Step`
- Sey use delta settings `Set Use Delta Settings Pipeline Step`
- Read Form Data [Custom***]
- Iterate and run pipelines `Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step`*(Add process single form pipeline to this step)*
- Submit entities to dynamics `Submit Remaining Entities From Queue Pipeline Step`

***Process single form pipeline***

- Read single form model `Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step`
- Resolve dynamics entity `Resolve Dynamics Entity By Identifier Pipeline Step`*(Point the identifier value accessor at the forms guid in source model, then use Guis as a string value reader)*
- Apply mapping from form model to incident `Apply Mapping Pipeline Step`*(Point to the mapping set from step 3)*
- Add incident to queue `Add Entity to Queue Pipeline Step`

**9. The custom step**

The custom step shown in the pipeline above, should be created using your new Read Form Data template. Specify the ItemId of the Form you are wanting to send, together with any additional settings. Add your converter and processor using your own namespace as appropriate: `*Yournamespace.ReadFormDataStepConverter, Yournamespace*`.

**10. Create a pipeline batch**

Create a new `Pipeline Batch` called **Forms to Dynamics Sync** in this location: `Dyanamics Tenant/Pipeline Batches` and add Read Forms Pipeline.

**11. Run Pipeline Batch**

Click the button to run the batch.

**Debug**

You are unlikely to get this working first time round. A good way to debug this process is to decompile the processor from Submit entities to dynamics step, create your own version and swap it in. Then place a breakpoint on the line where it calls dynamics:

```
crmServiceClient.Execute(executeMultipleRequest);
```

Here you can see the response from the dynamics call.
If your pipeline is not getting that far, then you can decompile the other processors in a similar way and step through those.